# Get MAX of COUNT in JPQL Query

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I'm attempting to retrieve the maximum number of employees across all departments with the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(n) FROM (SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Employee e GROUP BY e.department) n
```

This query is not able to be parsed, which I assume is the nested SELECT in the FROM clause. Is there any way to rewrite the query using only JPQL?

Edit: I also rewrote the query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Employee e GROUP BY e.department ORDER BY COUNT(e) DESC
```

Is fetching the top row of this query possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which I assume is the nested SELECT in the FROM clause

I would guess it's rather the fact that you're trying to apply the `MAX` aggregate function to the entire aliased rowset `n`, rather than to a specific column. Instead try:

```
SELECT MAX(n.employeeCount) 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(e) AS employeeCount FROM Employee e GROUP BY e.department) n
```

> Is fetching the top row of this query possible?

Sure, just use `query.setMaxResults(1)`